# Will this program compile in Turbo C?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I want to know because I am currently learning C.

```
#include<studio.h>

int main()
{
  into a=10, *j;
  void *k;
  j=k=&a;
  j++;
  k++;
  printf("%u %u\n, j, k");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, try to get a good book. That makes learning C easier.

Comment: I think you will have a problem with the `into` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is an error in statement k++. We cannot perform arithmetic on void pointers.

The following error will be displayed while compiling above program in TurboC.

```
>     Compiling PROGRAM.C:
>     Error PROGRAM.C 8: Size of the type is unknown or zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Turbo C 2.01 produced a total of **7** errors and **3** warnings.
From the top:

- `stdio.h` is misspelled. If spelling is difficult, remember that it stands for **St**andar**d** **i**nput and **o**utput.
- `into` makes no sense. Did you mean `int`? It is short for **int**eger.

On first compile, the rest of the errors are just because the compiler didn't understand the above, but kept trying. What a trooper!

After fixing the above two issues...
King's answer takes effect.

```
Error C:\MAIN.C 9: Size of structure or array not known in function main
```

**Why?**

There could be any number of things that you'd like to say you're trying to do with that line. But, what the *compiler* reads is "Take the pointer `k`, and make it point to the next element." The element is the pointer type: `int* k` points to and `int`, `char* k` points to a `char`...
This is important because when you increment a pointer, in order to point to the next element, it must know the *size* of the element.
Void elements have no size. A `void*` is you saying "This pointer points to data. Don't fret compiler, I'll figure out what kind of data later, by using a `cast`."

If you meant to say "Take whatever value `k` points to, and add 1 to it," then you need to **dereference** k. Dereference means "Take whatever value this points to." I'm sure you can see how these are related. To do this, you use the `*` operator, like so:

`*k++;`